# invite app users to an event using facebook application & notifications

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have read through http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/#invited

I am looking for a little clarification. When it states that "create_event" permission is required does this mean that every user who has connected with the application needs to have approved the create_event permission in order to receive the invite, or just the user who is the app owner/manager.

Also, is it still the case that you can now successfully send event invites to users of an app and it will appear in their upcoming event, but they will not get a notification via the globe icon in the header?

Is there a workaround for this? Using the requests dialogue is it possible for the app admin to send an update to all app users informing them of the event?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> When it states that "create_event" permission is required does this
>   mean that every user who has connected with the application needs to
>   have approved the create_event permission in order to receive the
>   invite

It means the *person using the app* must approve **create_event**. In fact, this is always the case with Facebook *permissions*, they apply to the person *using the app*. Furthermore, the invite can only be sent to that user's friends *not to other people using the app*. With a long-life access token you can invite *app users* but you must use a unique access per invite and it will be as if the user is inviting himself *via the app*.

> Also, is it still the case that you can now successfully send event
>   invites to users of an app and it will appear in their upcoming event,
>   but they will not get a notification via the globe icon in the header?

Last time I checked this was the case. I doubt it's changed because Facebook does not want to spam the notification globe with invites.

> Is there a workaround for this? Using the requests dialogue is it
>   possible for the app admin to send an update to all app users
>   informing them of the event?

Yes, you can use the requests dialog to force through a notification which when clicked may lead to a page that redirects to the event. However, the notification will only be generated for *user to user* requests **not** *app to user* requests. The latter increments certain counters, but does not generate a notification for the globe. Also note that you can only send 50 *user to user* requests at one time.

Comment: @Gil: How to send auto event invitation to users who has connected with the app? Please advice.