# Is it possible to invite users friends via open graph to an event created by an app on facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to invite users friends via open graph to an event created by an app on Facebook? Or does the user have to have created/own the event?

Similarly, is it possible to invite users friends via open graph to an event created by an page on Facebook? Or does the user have to have created/own the event?

Finally - is create_event required to be approved by the user, even if they are only inviting their friends to an event, not creating that event (as it has been created by the app/page)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can invite users to any event the user has access to (public event or invited to an event with invite permissions). However create_event permission is always required to invite. Keep in mind that users invited by an app will **not** receive notifications, however the event will appear in their upcoming events list.

More info:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Comment: Could you check my related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731362/invite-app-users-to-an-event-using-facebook-application-notifications